# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.5

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging, build.gradle

How to resolve this error!

> "Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.5"

Firebase dependencies version is `16.0.5`, I switch and play with some other versions also, still have the error.

```
  def Firebase_version = "16.0.5"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$Firebase_version"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$Firebase_version"
```

Am using latest version of classpath

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
 classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```

And repositories

```
google()
jcenter()
```

Both are added:

Android Studio : 3.2.1

Comment: Don't think you need this line: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'`

Comment: Are you 100% sure that version 16.0.5 exists? I can't see it in maven/google repository https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-messaging

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> firebase-messaging 16.0.x version seems unavailable, That why we
> getting the error
>
> > "Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:16.0.5"

In order to fix it keep the other 16.0.x versions as it is

and upgrade 17.x.x versions to the latest

code is given below

```
def Firebase_Auth_Version = "16.0.5"
def Firebase_Messaging_Version = "17.3.4"

 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$Firebase_Messaging_Version"
 implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$Firebase_Auth_Version"
```

Answer (score 4):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$Firebase_version"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$Firebase_version"
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
```

And add:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

Which is now mandatory in order to make Firebase work.

Answer (score 1):

Disable Gradle offline and re-syncing worked for me.

Comment: This was correct for me. but how to keep it offline

Answer (score 1):

What actually was missing for me and what made it work was 'Google Play services'

Go to: Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK Tools -> check/install Google Play services.

[image: SDK Tools Settings SS]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this *dependencies* as well.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
```

Try by adding above *dependencies.*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the app gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5'
```